# Closing a card on Gmail Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I would like to programmatically close the add-on after clicking a button.
Is is possible to close the addon programmatically?

Thank you

Comment: Did you do any research or testing? What happens if you [pop every Card?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no provision for closing the GMail add on programatically. User has to click on the add on icon on the side bar to close it.